# What will this code print on screen?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, set

I need help figuring out why when I run this code  it prints 
(8,8) (8,8) (0,8) (7,8) (6,8) (5,8) (4,8) (3,8) (1,8) (0,8) (8,8) on screen.
I don't understand how increment and decrement operators work on iterators `u` and `v` in function `g`.
I know that set will have elements 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. But I don't understand how "walking" through the set works.

```
template <typename T>
std::complex<double> g(T &u, T &v) { return {*--u, *v++}; }

std::set<int> s{3, 8, 4, 7, 0, 1, 1, 5, 7, 3, 6};
std::set<int>::iterator v(s.begin()), w(s.end());
while (v != w) std::cout << g(v, w) << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: You need to use some debugging method then. Use print debugging or use a debugger, and walk through the program line by line while it's running. That's how you see what's going on inside a program.

Comment: When *you* run it, what does it print? What did you expect? Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: I did do that, but I still don't understand why iterator v has constant value of 8.

Answer (score 2):

You're decrementing `s.begin()` and incrementing `s.end()`. Both result in *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: It's not my code. This was a question on my exam and I had to write what would this part do. I understand what happens when I decrement s.begin (v) but I don't understand what happens with w in g function.

Comment: @Lamija37 I'd say the only correct answer to that is *"Impossible to predict because of the undefined behaviour"*. If you want to know exactly what happens, why not look into the standard library code?